# how to defined the topics retention bytes and segment bytes so size of topic partition will no high the specific size

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

we have kafka cluster with `3 nodes`

kafka contain `5 topics` and each topic include `100 partitions`

bow we want to set the `retention bytes` and the `retention segment` in way that each topic partition will not high the `5G` ( because we are limited according to kafka disk size )

is it possible to tune the values of retention bytes and segment bytes , so no way that any topic partition will be high then `5G` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to cap the size of a topic. It's even possible that retention will go above `retention.bytes` if you push data into the topic faster than the LogCleaner thread has time to clean it up.

Also note that upcoming versions of Kafka [will offer infinite retention](https://www.confluent.io/blog/infinite-kafka-data-storage-in-confluent-cloud/)

Or you could similarly use tiered storage features of [Apache Pulsar](http://pulsar.apache.org/docs/en/concepts-tiered-storage/) instead of Kafka